# Biopython; ValueError: No records found in handle

Tags: biopython

```
gene = Entrez.efetch(db="gene", id="54901", rettype="gb", retmode="text" 
gene_record = SeqIO.read(gene,"gb")
```

> ValueError: No records found in handle

I don't understand why this happens, is it from the gene in question, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are getting this error. This code works great. Are you behind a proxy?

Look at this:

```
>>> gene = Entrez.efetch(db="gene", id="54901", rettype="gb", retmode="text")
>>> data = gene.read()
>>> print(data)

1. CDKAL1
Official Symbol: CDKAL1 and Name: CDK5 regulatory subunit associated protein 1-like 1 [Homo sapiens (human)]
Other Designations: tRNA-t(6)A37 methylthiotransferase
Chromosome: 6; Location: 6p22.3
Annotation: Chromosome 6NC_000006.12 (20534457..21232404)
MIM: 611259
ID: 54901
```